# vba equivalent of matlab logspace

Tags: vba, matlab, excel

hi experts kindly help me decode the logspace into vba

The matlab code is `n      = 2.^(0:floor(log2(N/2)))';

maxN = n(end);
endLogInc = log10(maxN);
m = unique(ceil(logspace(0,endLogInc,pts)))';`

where N = 604891 and pts is 5
the result in Matlab is
n =
        1
        2
        4
        8
       16
       32
       64
      128
      256
      512
     1024
     2048
     4096
     8192
    16384
    32768
    65536
   131072
   262144

maxN =  262144
endLogInc =  5.4185
m =

```
    1
   23
  513
11586
```

262145

How can i execute the same in vba for excel?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this implementation of [linspace and logspace](http://pfadintegral.com/articles/linspace-logspace-vba/)?

Comment: yeah. but i do not know how to display the answer when i call that function from a sub